# Obtaining the combination of elements in a dictionary

Tags: python, math

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
a: [a]
b: [b, c]
c: [d, e, f]
```

The number of keys and the number of elements in each list is unknown beforehand.

I would like to be able to obtain all the possible combinations of the elements in every list. The output for the above dictionary would be something like this:

```
[a, d, b]
[a, e, c]
[a, f, b]
[a, d, c]
[a, e, b]
[a, f, c]
```

Order for both the lists in the list and the elements in the lists in the list (that's a mouthful) doesn't matter.

I tried a solution which I have posted an answer to, but I am curious to find out if there are more efficient solutions.

EDIT: Only one element can be taken from every key in the dictionary. Following the example above, you can't have `[b d e]` as `d e` is from `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. I understand the question and corrected my answer.

Make the list of values using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> d = {"a": [1], "b": [2,3], "c": [4,5,6]}
>>> values = [v for k,v in d.items()]
>>> values
[[1], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3]]
```

Then use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) which is equivalent to for-loop.

```
>>> for i in itertools.product(*l):
...     print i
... 
(1, 4, 2)
(1, 4, 3)
(1, 5, 2)
(1, 5, 3)
(1, 6, 2)
(1, 6, 3)
```

Comment: There'd be overlapping instances, otherwise this would be a great solution. If a filter was incorporated to make sure only one element is taken from the list, that would work. Edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: Nice method, never knew of that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
def _gcd(a, b):
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def _lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // _gcd(a, b)

def lcm(numbers):
    return reduce(_lcm, numbers)

def combinations(dict):
    lengths = []
    for key in dict.keys():
        lengths.append(len(dict[key]))

    lcm_int = lcm(lengths)
    for key in dict.keys():
        values = []
        length = len(dict[key])
        for i in range(lcm_int):
            values.append(dict[key][i%length])
        dict[key] = values

    combinations = []
    for i in range(lcm_int):
        values = []
        for key in dict.keys():
            values.append(dict[key][i])
        combinations.append(values)
    return combinations
```

This code finds the LCM of the lengths of all lists in the dictionary. It then expands each list to something like this:

```
[a]       -> [a, a, a, a, a, a]
[b, c]    -> [b, c, b, c, b, c]
[d, e, f] -> [d, e, f, d, e, f]
```

Afterwards, it takes the first element of every list and places it in a new list (a combination) and does the same for the rest of the elements.

Comment: This method is overcomplicated and inefficient, so I didn't accept it. :P